# Nuxt3 load event not working how can I workable this

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm migrating my nuxt2 project to nuxt3, in my application many places I have used the `load` event for some operations but in v3 this `load` event not working anymore inside `lauouts/default.vue` other events working like `scroll, resize` but `load` doesn't

#### app.vue

```html
<template>
  <NuxtLayout />
</template>
```

#### layouts/default.vue

```html
<script setup>
if (process.client) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        alert('hello');
    });
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="w-full">
        <NavMainNav />

        <main class="h-auto">
            <slot />
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a code to be executed after the page is fully rendered and prepared, you can achieve that with Vue's [Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html), namely with `mounted` in this case.

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  if (process.client) {
    alert('Component just got mounted')
  }
})
</script>
```

Also there is a number of [Nuxt specific hooks](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/advanced/hooks) available. For example you can have:

```js
<script setup>
useNuxtApp().hook('app:mounted', () => alert('Vue app is ready and mounted in browser.'));
</script>
```

If you combine the two mentioned above, first `mounted` on the sole component will happen, then the "global" `app:mounted` hook will be triggered, as seen in [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lk7a3e?file=app.vue).

You may need to experiment a bit with the correct setup to achieve your goals, but hooks give you some solid power over your app.

Edit: another possible option for you might be [`onNuxtReady`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/on-nuxt-ready)